# Copy a subset of data between two objects

Tags: typescript

Given I have a type `A` and a type `B` like this:

```
type A = {
  firstName: string
  middleName?: string
  lastName: string  
}

type B = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  dateOfBirth: Date
}
```

Now I have an instance of `A`:

```
const a: A = { firstName: 'Alex', lastName: 'Zeitler' }
```

And I want to create an instance of `B` having data from `a`, I can do this:

```
const { firstName, lastName } = a
const b: B = { firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth: new Date() }
```

Is there a more efficient / shorter way of doing this?

I don't want to do this:

```
const b: B = { firstName: a.firstName, lastName: a: lastName, dateOfBirth: new Date() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could one-line it with spread syntax and a self-executing function:

```
const b = (({middleName, ...rest}) => ({...rest, dateOfBirth: new Date()}))(a);
```

I don't find that very readable though to be honest, I'd rather have what you've already got.

The nicest solution is probably to just name a function which does this specifically:

```
const bFromA = ({ firstName, lastName }: A): B => ({ 
  firstName, 
  lastName, 
  dateOfBirth: new Date()
})

const newB = bFromA(a);
```

Comment: You could also shorten it a bit by destructuring the argument directly: `const bFromA = ({ firstName, lastName }: A): B => ({ firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth: new Date() })`